# Why is my signal handler not working?

Tags: linux, signals

I want to handle the signal SIGTSTP (18) on Linux. This is my code:

```
void handler(int signum){
    printf("Signal %d has tried to stop me.", signum);
}

int main(void){
    struct sigaction act;
    sigset_t mask;

    act.sa_handler = handler;
    act.sa_flags = 0;

    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, SIGTSTP);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);

    sigaction(SIGTSTP, &act, NULL);

    pause();

}
```

When I send a signal from another terminal this way:

```
$ kill -18 PID
```

the handler() function does not run.
I've tried replacing SIGTSTP with 18 in the call to sigaction(). It does not work.

Any ideas?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deliberately blocking delivery of `SIGTSTP` to your process by doing

```
sigaddset(&mask, SIGTSTP);
sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask, NULL);
```

`sigprocmask` with `SIG_SETMASK` sets a mask to *block* signals. Remove the call to `sigprocmask`, and the signal should be delivered.

One other thing to do is to zero `act` before filling it in:

```
memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
```

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that you did not set your `struct sigaction act` to zero. It will be full of random stack values.

Fix it by using `struct sigaction act = {};` or `memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act))`

Double check that I got the memset argument order right. I sometimes get it mixed up.